# how to get decedents of a model in a view

Tags: django, django-models

I have two model objects: GEO, SHIP, and CREW.  There is a one-to-many relationship between crew, ship, and geo respectively.  There can be 0-n number of ships in a GEO.  with Each Ship, there can be 0-n 
if I pull the list of GEOs:

```
GEO = models.Geo.objects.all()
```

How do I refer to all of the GEOs, loop through SHIPS, and then with each ship, crew members...in the template?

Here's my model:

```
class Geo (Unit):
    coverage = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name


class Ship (Unit):
    HullNumber = models.TextField(null=True)
    Origin = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=ALLEGIENCE_CHOICES, default='FED')
    Geo = models.ForeignKey(Geo)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name


class Crew (models.Model):
    CrewType = (
        ('O', 'Officer'),
        ('E', 'Enlisted'),
        ('C', 'Civilian'),
    )
    Geo = models.ForeignKey(Geo)
    Ship = models.ForeignKey(Ship)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CrewType)
    Position = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Position
```

Thanks

Comment: try the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/ then try some code

Comment: For starters, show your model definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `views.py` you need to pass just a list of `Geo`:

```
def crew_list(request):
    return render(request, 'crew_list.html', {'geo_list': Geo.objects.all()})
```

A then in the template iterate over related ships/crew of each `Geo`:

```
{% for geo in geo_list %}
    <h1>{{ geo }}</h1>
    {% for ship in geo.ship_set.all %}
        <h2>{{ ship }}</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for crew in ship.crew_set.all %}
                <li>{{ crew }} - {{ crew.get_Type_display }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The another option is to pass to template a list of `Crew` ordered by Geo/Ship and use [ifchanged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag to show "changed" geo and ship of the crew member.